# Postgres : Difference between timestamp 'myTimestamp' and 'myTimestamp'::timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I stumbled upon this [S.O question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110910/performance-issues-with-inherited-tables-and-indices), which mentions that a check constraint has to be written like this:
`CHECK (ts >= timestamp '2015-08-11 00:00:00' AND ts < timestamp '2015-08-12 00:00:00')`

I am personally writing my type casts like this :
`CHECK (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp AND ts < '2015-08-12 00:00:00'::timestamp)`

Is 'timestamp' a type cast in the first example ?
Are both checks equivalent ? Is there any performance difference between the two ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you ! That instantly makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first syntax: `'2015-08-11 18:30:00'` is standard ANSI SQL to write a timestamp literal, this is also used for dates: `date '2015-08-11'` or just a time value: `time '18:30:00'`. This is a "constant" value, not a "cast" similar to simply writing `'foobar'` as a varchar constant.

The second form is a cast from a text value to a timestamp and is Postgres specific.